# Horizontally centering images with variable widths

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been going crazy with this: I have a banner which is structured like this:

```
<div id="header-image-wrapper">
    <a href="#content-title" id="header-link">
        <img id="bannerimage" src="image source" />
    </a>
</div>
```

The images won't always be the same width, and my client wants the image to be horizontally centered within the div. The div should have a maximum width of 1200px with overflow:hidden, so that if the image is larger than that, it will be centered and the excess on the left and right side will be cut off.

The only way I could think this would work was using javascript:

```
var imgWidth = document.getElementById('bannerimage').style.width/ 2;
document.getElementById('bannerimage').style.marginLeft = imgWidth;
```

But when I refresh the page, I get this error:

> [cycle] terminating; zero elements found by selector

Does anyone know what that means, and why it's happening? Also, if someone has a better solution to this problem, please share it as I'm at my wit's end. :)

Comment: I'm not quite understanding the problem. I think what you're trying to do is center a variable-width image. Assuming you kept the images as inline elements, does applying `text-align: center;` to the containing `<div>` element center the image properly?

Comment: "I think what you're trying to do is center a variable-width image. "
That's exactly what I'm trying to do. :) But the image is inside an <a> which is inside a <div>, and sadly, text-align:center doesn't do anything :(

Comment: How about making the image displayed block level (`display: block;`) and assigning `margin-left: auto;margin-right: auto;` to the image?

Comment: @DavidFaux `margin:0 auto;` works only for elements that have a defined width, so in this case it wouldn't work, right? Because I just tried it and it didn't.

Comment: Ok, I think I found the issue: the image is larger than its containing element. Could that be what's stopping the image from getting centered?

Comment: You are right.  I updated my answer below.  I think you should use a background image on the <a> tag.

Comment: Or assign the anchor a width of 100% and the image a max-width of 100%.  That will cause the image to scale itself down proportionally.

Comment: I ended up doing it using the image as a CSS background. :S Not ideal, but works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: (bottom one won't work if the image is too big, like you said, but this one should) Put the image as the background of the a tag and position it center.

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#header-image-wrapper {
text-align: center;
width: 1200px;
overflow: hidden;
}
#header-link {
    background-image: url("<Path to Your Image>");
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: block;
    width: 1200px;
    height: 300px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header-image-wrapper">
    <a href="#content-title" id="header-link">
    </a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I would just use CSS here.  Give the div an ID and then style it accordingly with "text-align: center"

```
<head>
<style>
#imgDIV {
text-align: center; //It's not only for text :)
width: 1200px;
overflow: hidden;
}
</style>
</head>
<div id="imgDIV">
   <img src="path to image">
</div>
```

Comment: I ended up making the image a CSS background instead of an inline image. Not sure if it's the best solution, but it's the only one that worked :D

Answer (score 1):

If it's just an image, why can't you do `text-align:center;` on the css?

```
<div style="text-align:center; width:1200px;">
    <img src="img.jpg" />
</div>
```

Comment: The image is inside an <a> tag and then inside a div. I tried using text-align:center and it didn't work :(

Answer (score 1):

Just use CSS:

```
#banner img {
  display: block;

  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

This won't account for the link, however. Applying it to the `#banner` only will center its contents as well.

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` for centering an image might be overkill

Comment: The image was wrapped in an <a> tag, so that might be making a difference?

Answer (score 1):

You can use block display and auto margin for img tag.

```
<div style="overflow:hidden; width:1200px;">
<a href="your link"><img src="imagepath" style="margin:auto; display:block" /></a>
```